# problem solving links that turn white (invisible) once clicked

Tags: html, email, colors, hyperlink

Someone wrote a solution to this problem is
*"adding a strong tag around the link text prevents it from turning purple on click. If you dont want the link to be bold just add font-weight:normal to the strong tag"*

works but how/where do I put "font-weight: normal"?

Answer (score 1):

You could just give it a color, that will keep it from changing on click:

```
<a href="#" style="color: blue;">link</a>
```